# first php query error

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm trying to write my first PHP query and I'm getting the following

**error:**

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   D:\Home\web\username\helloworld.php on line 36.

What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);

$servername = "myserver.com";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: plz define your question perfectely..

Comment: it would help to indicate which of your code is line 36 because you only posted 29 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so your code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

The Problem lies in `$result->num_rows > 0`

Apparently you have an Error in your query so your `$result` is a **boolean** instead of an Object, so the property `num_rows` **doesnt exist**. A better solution would be:

```
if($result !==false){
    //handle your result here
}else{
    echo "An error appeared: ".$conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I found out I do not have permission to do a SELECT command on that server with the code you provided.  I'll stop banging my head on the table now.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax and logic is correct but the query is not executing successfully. Try putting an `if` condition before the `if ($result->num_rows > 0)` condition to check that.

Also, I was able to reproduce the error by misspelling the name of the table. So, are you sure that the table `books` exists in your database? Correcting that will solve it.

Comment: I am sure about the books table.  I can run that query straight from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and get results.

Comment: You can not access MySQL databases from the Microsoft SSMS. It seems that the problem is you have created your database and tables in SQL and you are trying to use that from MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a problem with it. Have you got a table called books? Did you spell it wrong?

Your code: `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` is causing the problem because the query didn't return a success. So how can it get the `num_rows`?

You want to check for a MySql error before you run that if statement so try this final code and find out what the error is:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);

$servername = "myserver.com";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result !== false){
    //query was a success!
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}else{
    //your query had an error so lets display it:
    echo "Query Error: ".$conn->error;
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

What is the Error you now get printed out?